# In Django, when someone uploads a text file, how do I turn it into a String?

Tags: python, django

```
thefile = request.FILES.get("uploaded_file","")
```

Now, how do I turn that into a string of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to read it.

```
thefile.read()
```

Comment: WTF is that semicolon doing there 0_o